# Bamboo node_modules artifact

Tags: vue.js, continuous-integration, bamboo

I have a Vue application that I want to test, build and deploy automatically via Atlassian Bamboo. I set up several stages, and in each build job I have to do an `npm install` to get all the deps for testing, building etc.

So I tried to make the first build job share an artifact of the `node_modules` directory and let the following jobs depend on that, so that they don't need to `npm install` again. The artifact setting is:

- Location: `./node_modules`
- Copy pattern: `**`

Sadly, this does not work, as I get the following error in the next build job:

```
> frontend@4.0.0-alpha test:e2e-ci /var/atlassian/application-data/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/131073/CC-CC4-E2E
build   12-Mar-2019 09:42:35    > vue-cli-service test:e2e --headless -r mocha-bamboo-reporter -o output=report.cypress.json
build   12-Mar-2019 09:42:35    
error   12-Mar-2019 09:42:35    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
error   12-Mar-2019 09:42:35        throw err;
error   12-Mar-2019 09:42:35        ^
error   12-Mar-2019 09:42:35    
error   12-Mar-2019 09:42:35    Error: Cannot find module '../package.json'
error   12-Mar-2019 09:42:35        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
error   12-Mar-2019 09:42:35        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
error   12-Mar-2019 09:42:35        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
error   12-Mar-2019 09:42:35        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
error   12-Mar-2019 09:42:35        at Object.<anonymous> (/var/atlassian/application-data/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/131073/CC-CC4-E2E/node_modules/.bin/    vue-cli-service:5:25)
error   12-Mar-2019 09:42:35        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
error   12-Mar-2019 09:42:35        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
error   12-Mar-2019 09:42:35        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
error   12-Mar-2019 09:42:35        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
error   12-Mar-2019 09:42:35        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
error   12-Mar-2019 09:42:35    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
error   12-Mar-2019 09:42:35    npm ERR! errno 1
error   12-Mar-2019 09:42:35    npm ERR! frontend@4.0.0-alpha test:e2e-ci: `vue-cli-service test:e2e --headless -r mocha-bamboo-reporter -o     output=report.cypress.json`
error   12-Mar-2019 09:42:35    npm ERR! Exit status 1
error   12-Mar-2019 09:42:35    npm ERR! 
error   12-Mar-2019 09:42:35    npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@4.0.0-alpha test:e2e-ci script.
error   12-Mar-2019 09:42:35    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
error   12-Mar-2019 09:42:36    
error   12-Mar-2019 09:42:36    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
error   12-Mar-2019 09:42:36    npm ERR!     /opt/atlassian/bamboo/.npm/_logs/2019-03-12T08_42_35_772Z-debug.log
```

I `gzip`'ed the artifact `node_modules`, the one in the build job who builds the artifact and the one in the build job depending on it. The archives all have different sizes. Does Bamboo make mistakes when copying?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this by `tar`ing the node_modules in the first job, sharing the archive as artifact and un-`tar` the file in every other job.